# compare double in hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to compare a double value in Hibernate Criteria but it never finds the result.

in my entity i have

```
                            @Column(name = "ball")
                            private double ball;
```

in my query i am doing this

```
       public findBall(double ballNo)
     session = sessionFactory.openSession();
     Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(MyEntity.class);
     crit.add(Restrictions.eq("ball", new Double(ballNo))
```

but it always say there is no match , where as i can see in my db that this exact value is there

for some values it finds the result but for some it dont

any idea whats the reason

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Double` instead of `double` in the mapped class.

```
private Double ball;
```

It will be useful if you have NULL in the database as well.

Comment: still dloing the same behavior